# Use cancellation token to cancel execution of multiple tasks executed using Task.WhenAll<tasks> method in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, task, background-service, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I am working on an asp.net core application which has downloading files functionality. Using this function we can create multiple download tasks and execute them at once using `Task.Whenall`.

I am trying to implement cancel download functionality using which we can abort/cancel the complete download operation by clicking a cancel button on one of my razor pages (if I selected 100 files to download and clicked cancel after downloading 10 files, 90 remaining files should not be downloaded).

Currently it cannot be cancelled, once the download operation is started it continuously executes in background even if we close the download page unless all files fail/succeed to download. Exiting the application stops it.

Implementation is as follows.

DownloadsController class:

```
//variable declaration
CancellationTokenSource cts;
    
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download_iles(DownloadFilesModel downloadFilesModel)
{
     cts=new CancellationTokenSource(); 
     var successFiles = await _downloadManager.DownloadAsyncpa(downloadFilesModel.param1, downloadFilesModel.param2, cts.Token);
 }
```

ManageFileDownlods class:

```
 public class ManageFileDownlods : BackgroundService, IManageFileDownlods
 {
     //Constructor
      public ManageFileDownlods(IDownloadmaster downloadmaster)
        {
            _downloadmaster = downloadmaster;
        }
        
    public async Task<List<DownloadFile>>      
  DownloadAsync (funcparam1,funcparam2,CancellationToken cancellationToken=default)
    {
      // For each server in serverQueue these multiple tasks will execure
        while (serverQueue.Count > 0)
        {   
            //Multiple tasks created to downloadfiles
            downloadTasksList.Add(ServerProcess(funcparam1, funcparam2, cancellationToken));
            //Multiple tasks executed here to download files
            try
            {
            await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasksList.ToArray());  
            }
            catch()
            { }             
        }            
    }
    
private async Task<List<DownloadFile>> ServerProcess (funcparam1, funcparam2,         
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
             while (funcparam1.Count > 0)
            {
                //5 taks created in loop
              for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
              {
                    //Multiple tasks created to downloadfiles
               fileDownlodTasks.Add(_downloadmaster.Download(param1, param2,    
              cancellationToken));
                    await Task.Delay(300);
                }

                try
                {
                    //Multiple tasks executed here to download files
                    await Task.WhenAll(fileDownlodTasks.ToArray());                     
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("execution stopped");
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
      }
 }
```

Downloadmaster Class:

```
     public async Task<DownloadFile> Download (param1,param2,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //actual function which initiated file download from server
        var filecontents = DownloadFileFromServer (param1,param2, cancellationToken);
    }
```

I've spent much time on internet, gone through a lot of different articles over cancellation of tasks, tried to implement multiple approaches given in these articles, but unable to cancel the operation.

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but it certainly needs to be fixed: never do `throw ex;` where `ex` is a caught exception. You'll lose your stack trace, making it more difficult to debug. Instead, just do `throw;` which will properly preserve the stack trace.

Comment: You created your own cancellation token source - that means you need to call cancel on it in order to cancel it. Rather than making your own cancellation token source, it's probably better to get a cancellation token from the action method parameters.

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example. To cancel properly, the `cts` needs to be canceled at some point *and* the `DownloadFileFromServer` method must observe the cancellation.

Comment: Stephen Cleary,
you mean cts.Cancel() method should be somewhere inside DownloadFileFromServer() method? I have intialized Cancellationtokensoiurce in controller action method. and passed the token to the service. Is that correct ? or  should  I intialize Cancellationtokensoiurce  in Downloadmaster Class?

Comment: Mason, As you can see in code snippet, I am passing token from controller method as a parameter to service method and so on to the main Downloadfilefromserver method. Isn't this  a correct approach?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should add CancellationToken to the action parameters. ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core map that parameter to [HttpContext.RequestAborted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.requestaborted?view=aspnetcore-7.0) token. More details [here](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/)